# Unable to establish connection between Zookeeper and Kafka on Apple M1 using docker-compose

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper, apple-m1

I am trying to run Kafka + Zookeeper through docker-compose.yml

```yaml
`version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.4.9
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
        ZOO_MY_ID: 1
        ZOO_PORT: 2181
        # ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zookeeper:2888:3888;2181
    volumes:
      - ./data/zookeeper/data:/data
      - ./data/zookeeper/datalog:/datalog

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.0
    hostname: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9091:9091"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka1:19091,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9091
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - ./data/kafka1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

However, Kafka is unable to connect with the ZooKeeper

```
kafka101-kafka1-1     | [main-SendThread(zookeeper:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: zookeeper/172.19.0.2:2181: Connection refused
kafka101-kafka1-1     | [main-SendThread(zookeeper:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zookeeper/172.19.0.2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```

I checked and confirmed that the Zoo keeper is running

```
ps -ef | grep zookeeper
    1 zookeepe   0:19 {java} /usr/bin/qemu-x86_64 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin/java -Dzookeeper.log.dir=. -Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE -cp /zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../build/classes:/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.9.jar:/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/conf: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain /conf/zoo.cfg
```

The zoo configuration looks like this:

```
clientPort=2181
dataDir=/data
dataLogDir=/datalog
tickTime=2000
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
```

Telnet output directly from zookeeper is :

```
zookeeper-3.4.9 # telnet localhost 2181
telnet: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
```

ping to zookeeper host in kafka1

```
> ping zookeeper
PING zookeeper (172.19.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
PING zookeeper (172.19.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.

PING zookeeper (172.19.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

I am running on Apple M1 Chipset

What else can I check and do here?

Answer (score 3):

Try using confluentinc's zookeeper image: `confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest`

I was in the *exact* same boat, also on the M1 chip and this worked for me.

These are the two services from my docker-compose for ref:

```
  zoo:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_PORT: 2181
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo:2888:3888
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zoo:2181'
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: 'kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    depends_on:
      - zoo
```